# Searching for API that returns most popular movies/tv

Tags: api, streaming, rapidapi

So I'm developing a coding project on the side with othersto learn more about APIs. Currently we're hoping to tie something together that will let you search for a movie and return what platforms it's streaming on and what it costs.

Currently we've worked out something involving searching off IMDB API to get the IMDB ID and use that in combination with Utelly to get some information on where it's available. We're mostly planning to do this with cheaply available information. However we'd like to be able to have a default in searching that it'll just pull the top most popular tv or movies.

Does anyone know any API that contain that information that would be free and allow at least a few dozen hits a day or so? By most popular what comes to mind is most downloads or top watches, but I suppose top rated could work in a pinch. APIs that are hosted on RapidAPI would be preferred though not required. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess [OTT details](https://rapidapi.com/gox-ai-gox-ai-default/api/ott-details/) is a good API that can fit the bill for you. However, you can search for other movie-related APIs on RapidAPI as well. Read the documentation and try to play around with the APIs.

Here is the sample response of OTT details API. There are several other endpoints as well which you can test.

[image: Example response of OTT details API]